# How can "going with" and "went" be used together in a sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, usage

And, of course, going with these social distinctions went an ideology that higher classes had breeding and refinement built into them which set them apart from what seemed to be the rough-hewn or ‘common’ nature of those who made up the lower social classes.

Comment: I do not understand your question, its body has a fine example of how to use the two items in one sentance. Perhaps you can explain what you understand by this sentence, or what you believe to be wrong with it.

Comment: Please read the first sentence carefully; going with these social ~~ went an ideology

Comment: I did read it carefully. What do you think is wrong with saying "went an ideology"? The sentance says there are two things, namely "social distinctions" and "an ideology that ... into them". These two things "set them [i.e. the higher classes] apart from ...".

Comment: In the sentence, the subject is 'an ideology" and the verb is "went", which is an inversion.  Then What is "the phrase "going with"?  An ideology[ that~] went going with these social distinctions. I don't understand this sentence. Can you explain  what role "going and went" play respectively? and the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Your last comment should have been edited into the question so as to express what you found difficult about the sentence. The answer from @ThePhoton nicely summarises the reason I did not understand your problem with the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It is redundant. Both "going with" and "went" are expressing that social distinctions and the ideology were closely related. Native English speakers aren't noticing the issue because this kind of redundancy is part of everyday speech and informal writing. A careful editor would probably have caught this redundancy and asked the writer to rephrase the sentence.

Overall, the example is something of a run-on, trying to combine too many concepts into one sentence. I wouldn't consider this an example of really careful writing. But it's also the kind of writing you're likely to see from native speakers very commonly, so you should learn to decode it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Reword:

> And, of course, along with these social distinctions went an ideology that...

I might add that the words "And, of course,..." don't add much to the sentence.